# Count of Comma separated values in r

Tags: r

I have a column named *subcat_id* in which the values are stored as comma separated lists.  I need to count the number of values and store the counts in a new column.  The lists also have Null values that I want to get rid of.

[image: Example]

I would like to store the counts in the *n* column.

Comment: Do not post your data as an image, please learn how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)

Answer (score 4):

We can try

```
 nchar(gsub('[^,]+', '', gsub(',(?=,)|(^,|,$)', '', 
      gsub('(Null){1,}', '', df1$subcat_id), perl=TRUE)))+1L
 #[1] 6 4
```

---

Or

```
library(stringr)
str_count(df1$subcat_id, '[0-9.]+')
#[1] 6 4
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- data.frame(subcat_id = c('1,2,3,15,16,78', 
        '1,2,3,15,Null,Null'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
sapply(strsplit(subcat_id,","),FUN=function(x){length(x[x!="Null"])})
```

`strsplit(subcat_id,",")` will return a list of each item in *subcat_id* split on commas.  `sapply` will apply the specified function to each item in this list and return us a vector of the results.

Finally, the function that we apply will take just the non-null entries in each list item and count the resulting sublist.

For example, if we have

```
subcat_id <- c("1,2,3","23,Null,4")
```

Then running the above code returns `c(3,4)` which you can assign to your column.

---

If running this from a dataframe, it is possible that the character column has been interpreted as a factor, in which case the error *non-character argument* will be thrown.  To fix this, we need to force interpretation as a character vector with the `as.character` function, changing the command to

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(frame$subcat_id),","),FUN=function(x){length(x[x!="Null"])})
```

Comment: Error in strsplit(test2$subcat_id, ",") : non-character argument using your commands am getting the error

Comment: @Sandy2511 I have edited the answer to address that (which is caused by the dataframe treating the column as a factor).  See the note at the end of my answer.

Comment: excellent and thanks for the help ,you explanation to the task was wonderfull

Comment: @Sandy2511 You're welcome and I'm glad that I could help.  If this answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it.